# How minify angular code using jhon papa style

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How minify angular code using angular style by jhon papa. The question arises as reserved words are passed framework . Below I present the two forms

**Normal**

```
var app;
app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myController',['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){

   //Procesos a ejecutar

}]);
```

**Jhon Papa Style**

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myController', myController)

 function myController(){

   //Do stuff

 };
```

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call the $inject method, and pass the dependencies as normal.

For instance, in your example if you were to inject data you would call

```html
myController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http'];
```

Comment: Thanks, that was what I was looking for